# Can I define a delegate as the restriction of a function in c#?

Tags: c#, delegates

Suppose i have two functions: f(x,y) and g(x). In mathematics, if you have a fixed y, say y_fix, you can define:

```
g(x) := f(x,y_fix)
```

Now suppose that g() is a c# delegate, and f is an implemented function.
Can I define g(x) in an analogous way? e.g.

```
public delegate double SingleVariableFunction(double x);
public class SomeClass
{
    SingleVariableFunction g;
    double y_fix;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        y_fix = 2;
        g = f(  ,y_fix);    /// Is this possible somehow?
    }

    public double f(double x, double y)
    {
        return x + y;   
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `g = f(  ,y_fix);` supposed to represent? Is the `,` a typo?

Comment: @Blorgbeard It's the mystery first argument to `f()`. That's the OP's question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).

In C# you can construct `g` with lambda expression:

```
g = x => f(x, y_fix);
```

Comment: Awesome @just.ru ! C# is So Well Done !